# php oop call method from another class

Tags: php, oop, dependencies, solid-principles

I'm new to OOP. I'm trying to keep the SOLID principles. Got some questions. This is my code. Is there a way to access the `class FileManager` methods in `class GenericUploader`(use abstract class because I can provide some base functionality) when I pass as dependency `class Image()`, `class Video()` or something else in UploaderClient? Goal is always to have access to `class FileManager` methods, no metter if I pass as dependency image, video or filemanager?

```
interface IFile
{
    public function crete(array $data);
}

interface IFileManager extends IFile
{
    public function exist(int $id);
}

class FileManager implements IFileManager
{
    public function crete(array $data)
    {
        // store in DB files
    }

    public function exist()
    {

    }
}

class Image implements IFile
{
    public function crete(array $data)
    {
        //access to FileManager
        // store in DB image and files
    }
}

abstract class GenericUploader
{
    public $service;

    public function __construct(IFile $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        //access to FileManager if $service is new Image()
    }
}

class ImageUploader extends GenericUploader
{
    public function __construct(IFile $service)
    {
        parent::__construct($service);
    }
}

class FileManagerUploader extends GenericUploader
{
    public function __construct(IFile $service)
    {
        parent::__construct($service);
    }
}

class UploaderClient
{
    public function uploadFile(IFile $service)
    {
        $name = get_class($service);
        $uploaderClass = $name . 'Uploader';

        if (class_exists($uploaderClass)) {
            $uploader = new $uploaderClass($service);
            $uploader->upload();
        }
    }
}

$client = new UploaderClient();
$client->uploadFile(new Image());
$client->uploadFile(new FileManager());
```

**Update**: if I extend Image, for example

```
class Image extends FileManager implements IFile
    {
        public function crete(array $data)
        {
            //access to FileManager
            // store in DB image and files
        }
    }
```

Is it wrong to access class FileManage methods on that way ($this->service->exist) from GenericUploader? Does it violate open/close principles?

Comment: If you always use methods of `FileManager`, why don't you add it to `IFile` interface?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood write your question - please try my code. There is one `trait`, and it can help you:

**UPD**:

```
interface IFile
{
    public function crete(array $data);
}

// You can only implement interface, but not extends
class Image implements IFile
{
    public function crete(array $data)
    {
        //access to FileManager
        // store in DB image and files
    }
}

class FileManager implements IFile
{
    public function crete(array $data)
    {
        // store in DB files
    }

    public function exist(int $id)
    {

    }
}

abstract class GenericUploader extends FileManager
{
    public $service;

    public function __construct(IFile $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        //access to FileManager if $service is new Image()
    }
}

class ImageUploader extends GenericUploader
{
    public function __construct(IFile $service)
    {
        parent::__construct($service);
    }
}

class FileManagerUploader extends GenericUploader
{
    public function __construct(IFile $service)
    {
        parent::__construct($service);
    }
}

class UploaderClient
{
    public function uploadFile(IFile $service)
    {
        $name = get_class($service);
        $uploaderClass = $name . 'Uploader';

        if (class_exists($uploaderClass)) {
            $uploader = new $uploaderClass($service);
            $uploader->upload();
        }
    }
}

$client = new UploaderClient();
$client->uploadFile(new Image());
$client->uploadFile(new FileManager());
```

Comment: ok, but in that case what about for FileManagerUploader. If I use trait and pass FileManager as dependency($client->uploadFile(new FileManager). I want to use FileManager standalone also.

Comment: GenericUploader class is generic for Image, Video, FileManager, in this case $client->uploadFile(new FileManager()) IFile $service and extended FileManager class is the same object.

Comment: Same classes, but not same objects